# Printed or digital story featuring nuke alien trapped in crashing ISS

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novel

I remember participating in a newsgroup thread in late 90s. The thread was created by a sci-fi writer (or, a lunatic who claimed he was a writer). In the end, he said he was going to publish these ideas into a book. I don't know he published it or not. Even if he never published it, I believe this should be on-topic here because we allow fan fictions.

There were thousands of messages in the thread. So, I never even had time to read all of them, but I remember main points from finalized draft:

- A small alien spaceship crash lands in ISS which would disrupt its orbit and it'd go on course to crash on Earth.
- NASA would adjust ISS's course to make it crash into ocean.
- Later, they would come to know that the crash would destroy half the planet. Initially, alien spaceship's engine was planned as a cause of destruction, but later I pushed an idea of making head of the alien go nuclear and OP loved it.
- In the end, the Earth was saved, but I don't remember how.

Can you identify this as published short story, book or Internet fan fiction?

I have already searched Usenet for 90s. It's not in my mind which newgroup it was. I just remember using email (Hotmail) to send or receive messages. I have also forgotten which email address I used (which I can find if I look but my personal cloud is very big), but there were two words in it: "rocket" and "cosmos/cosmic". Also, the OP's email address contained the word "ninja." It's possible that the newsgroup archive would mask the email today, so you can look for name in header "Rocket".

Comment: +1 for *or, a lunatic who claimed he was the writer* :-)